# Dynamically add new set of textboxes

Tags: rsform

Is there a way that RSForms can insert dynamic boxes when a trigger is clicked?

For example, if someone has three children to sign up for a class and there is only one text box for one child's information, is there a way to have a trigger that says `"Add A Child"` and a set of text boxes will display?

Comment: You would be best to contact the developers of RS Form for such a customisation.

Comment: It's not an option to create a loop with their product.

Comment: It might be easier to have a drop down field or similar for the number of children and then use JavaScript to display the required number of fields. This is easy to do in ChronoForms v5 but I'm not sure about RSForms.